# Relationship in schemaless OrientDb

Tags: java, relationship, orientdb, schemaless

In a schema-less how are made the relationship: embedded or referenced?

I can read in ODocument API that If I use the method

```
public ODocument field(String iFieldName,
          Object iPropertyValue,
          OType iFieldType)
```

to add a new field, I force the field type instead of to be auto-determined. I guess that by this function I can chose the type of relationship. But, if I don't use this method, which is the way to auto-determine the relationship type?

In this example:

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument("Person");
doc.field( "name", "Luke" );
doc.field( "surname", "Skywalker" );
doc.field( "city", new ODocument("City").field("name","Rome").field("country", "Italy"))
```

city is embedded or referenced? If it's embedded how can I make it referenced or vice versa?

Thanks!
aGO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the property as embedded in the schema, or use the type on the fly while setting the property:

```
doc.field( "city", new ODocument("City").field("name","Rome").field("country", "Italy"),
                OType.EMBEDDED)
```

Embedded documents hasn't own RID.

Comment: Ok, but just to understand better, in this example (schema-less) doc.field( "city", new ODocument("City").field("name","Rome").field("country", "Italy")) City is embedded or referenced?

Comment: By default is always linked, not embedded.